not receiving form submission in my email after activating form
after activating form and changing to the random-like string provided in place of my email, i stopped receiving mail submissions.
<form action="https://formsubmit.co/575d69f02e5db065e290ea3a1ba5774f" method="POST" class="newsletter " id="newsletter1-form">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label class="newsletter-header">Never miss an offer</label>
                        <label class="newsletter-subheader">Subscribe and be the first to receive our exclusive
                            offers.</label>
                        <div class="form" id="newsletter-form">
                            <input type="hidden" name="access_key" value="3c50f320-8587-4db8-845d-e0ae729fecfa">
                            <div class="form-item1 form-itemA">
                                <input id="newsletter_email" type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name"
                                    required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-item1 form-itemA">
                                <input id="newsletter_email" type="text" name="last-name" placeholder="Last Name"
                                    required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-item1 form-itemN">
                                <input id="newsletter_email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email"
                                    required />
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-container" id="newsletter-btn">
                                <input id="submit" class="btn btn-glow form-btn" type="submit" name="Newsletter Subscription"
                                    value="Subscribe" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="newslettersuccess-wrapper">
                            Thank you for subscribing to our newsletter!

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

I switched back to my previous email and still not receiving mails
